# What is the correct way to use Inject dependencies Dagger in a project with both Java & Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I am using Dagger for dependency injection. The project includes both Java & Kotlin. Dependency injection in Java works fine, now I am creating code in Kotlin and receive errors are cropping up. I am using `kapt` for the `annotationProcessor`

I am injecting the dependency in the Fragment. I am trying to inject the ViewModelFactory(It works when I don't use dependency injection in Kotlin).

`@Inject
    lateinit var factoryViewModel: ViewModelFactory`

The above code results in error

`error: cannot access NotNull class file for org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull not found Consult the following stack trace for details.`

If I try:

`@Inject
     var factoryViewModel: ViewModelFactory?=null`

I get the error

```
error: Dagger does not support injection into private fields
private com.package.id.ViewModelFactory factoryViewModel;
```

The ViewModelFactory is bound in ViewModelModule

```
@Module
public abstract class ViewModelModule {
@Binds
public abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory 
bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);
...
}
```

The app component which is instantiated in the Application class is

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    AppModule.class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
    ActivityBuilder.class,
    ViewModelModule.class
})

public interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance Builder application(MyApplication application);
    Builder appModule(AppModule appModule);
    AppComponent build();
}

void inject(MyApplication application);

}      

                                                   `
```

The Activity & Fragment classes are defined below.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import dagger.android.AndroidInjection
import dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector
import dagger.android.support.HasSupportFragmentInjector
import javax.inject.Inject

class ConnectedActivity : AppCompatActivity(),HasSupportFragmentInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

override fun supportFragmentInjector(): DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> {
    return dispatchingAndroidInjector
}


private fun configureDagger() {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    configureDagger()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, ConnectedFragment.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
    }
}

}

class ConnectedFragment : Fragment() {


companion object {
    fun newInstance() = ConnectedFragment()
}
@Inject
var factoryViewModel: ViewModelFactory?=null
lateinit var connectedViewModel: ConnectedViewModel

private fun configureDagger() {
    AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    this.configureDagger()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    var rootView:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connected_fragment, container, false)
    connectedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factoryViewModel).get(ConnectedViewModel::class.java)

    return rootView
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}


}
```

Any advice on how to inject it correctly.

Comment: But did you apply `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`?

Comment: yes, it is added to the `build.gradle` file of the module. The project is multi module. So its in all the required modules

Comment: Would there be a problem as ViewModelFactory & ViewModelKey are written in Java? This is since I have previous dagger code in Java